# Need to customise the pop up alert for SKStoreReviewController

Tags: ios, swift

In my project, I have to show the App rating inside the application.So I have import the StoreKit in the last screen and called the below line:

```
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
```

It's working as expected like below image:
https://clevertap.com/blog/improve-ios-app-ratings-with-skstorereviewcontroller/

Is it possible to customise the alert pop up to add some other information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to customise the alert pop up to add some other information?

No. It's not your alert. There is nothing you can do except ask for it to be presented.